# HTML onchange (this.value)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

We found this in our code (we haven't written it by our selfs, and we are new to programmng), can anyone explain what this.value means and how you change it?

```
<select id="sel_target" onchange="paint(this.value);sendid(value); highlight(value);move_to(value)">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

this.value represents the selected value.

Example:

```
function getComboA(sel) {
    var value = sel.value;  
}

<select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
<option value="">Select combo</option>
<option value="Value1">Text1</option>
<option value="Value2">Text2</option>
<option value="Value3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

The above example gets you the selected value [OnChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But whats the difference between (this.value) and (value)?We are trying to run the function paint with a specific value but can't understand how to do it.

Comment: this as a keyword that "evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context" and this.value indicates current selected value. where as value gives you all the values of dropdown

Comment: cant we pass event to getComboA instead of this and use event.target.value - What's the benefit of using this.value over event.target.value ?