# How to open a new page with Perl CGI popup menu

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, window.open

I wish, from the Perl-cgi script below, to open a new page when we select an item in the menu; as we do with window.open.
If anyone has an idea on how I can execute a command similar to : window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

thank you in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use CGI ;
my $cgi = new CGI;
my %url = (
    "https://www.google.com"    => "google" ,
    "https://www.msn.com"       => "msn",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"     => "yahoo" 
);
print $cgi->header("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
print "<!DOCTYPE html>";
print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print '<form>'."\n";
print $cgi->popup_menu(
  - name     => 'url',
  - id       => 'url',
  - values   => [sort keys %url],
  - default  => ['google'],
  - labels   => \%url,
  - onchange => 'submit();'
    #- onchange => "this.form.submit();"
);
print "</form>\n";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

Comment: Please be aware that the use of the CGI module (CGI.pm) is discouraged; particularly the HTML-generation methods are [deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used), and the module recommends using a templating system such as Template::Toolkit instead.

Answer (score 3):

You nearly have it, but you probably want [`this.value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477105/html-onchange-this-value).

```
print $cgi->popup_menu(
  - name     => 'url',
  - id       => 'url',
  - values   => [sort keys %url],
  - default  => ['google'],
  - labels   => \%url,
  - onchange => q{window.open(this.value, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');},
);
```

But as I commented, since these CGI methods are deprecated, please do consider using an alternative such as [Template::Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/). A common pattern in TT is to have two files that might look as follows.

The Perl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

# my_form.cgi

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use HTTP::Headers;
use Template;

my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new;
$headers->header('Content-Type' =>  'text/html;charset=UTF-8');
print $headers->as_string;

my %urls = (
    "https://www.google.com"    => "google" ,
    "https://www.msn.com"       => "msn",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"     => "yahoo" 
);

my $template = Template->new;
$template->process('my_form.ttml', { urls => \%urls });
```

The Template file:

```
[%# my_form.ttml %]
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <select name="url"  id="url" onchange="window.open(this.value, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');">
    [% FOREACH url IN urls -%]
      <option value="[% url.key %]">[% url.value %]</option>
    [% END -%]
  </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can look at [Template::Manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual.pod) and [Template::Manual::Intro](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Intro.pod) for details on Template::Toolkit, or you can look at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for more inspiration.

Comment: Thank you **Possum** for your quick response, and also for the advice regarding the use of CGI's alternative method.

Comment: @Tony92 Happy to help! If you feel like this answered your question, please mark the answer "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks.